# Update the Super User FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, faq-update-request

With the changes made to the policies recently, and the amount of hits Super User is taking at the moment, I would like to suggest that the current FAQ is updated as follows:

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about ...
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> … and it is not about
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like facebook, twitter and wordpress
> - cellphones or mobile devices excluding iPhones
> - electronic devices or media players
>
> then you're in the right place to ask your question!

I don't believe it should be a big list but these are the common one's that seems to cause tension during the closing of questions. It's useful to just direct people to the FAQ rather then having to type a comment every time.

Comment: SU is under attack?

Comment: When is it not? Drive by shootings, fly by night questions. I can safely say SU will never have a 100% answer accept rate.

Comment: It's time to clean this mess up, I know just what this town, umm website needs.

Comment: Should the FAQ of SU point to some of the meta discussions that became tagged FAQ?

Comment: @Troggy The FAQ should remain simple. The average user doesn't even have to know about a discussion/faq question on meta, for simple rules. Giving link later for more precision seems a good thing still. But on the first sight, I don't think there should be link to something more complicated, just simple rules.

Comment: @Gnoupi:  I think it is simply a miracle in the first place if someone even clicks on the FAQ and even looks at it.

Comment: @Troggy: true, but that's something they are "supposed to" have done before posting a question, as opposed to checking FAQ questions on meta. Referring to the FAQ should refer indeed to simple rules.

Comment: @Gnoupi - All the FAQ's already link to Meta's FAQ tags - Right at the bottom. There is no need for more, **however** the level of SU users require the front FAQ to be updated a bit more clearly, due to issues when closing questions, which is why I tried to keep it simple.

Comment: @Diago - Wow, I link to this so often, and I never noticed this link at the bottom. Besides, I notice that the FAQ has been updated with a larger range for smartphones than the one proposed, nice.

Comment: About websites in this FAQ update, see my "question" on this other topic: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15161/should-questions-concerning-specific-websites-be-allowed-on-superuser/35999#35999

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're absolutely right Diago! This way there doesn't have to be a discussion about why Facebook questions are closed.

Plus it might help offering suggestions to alternative Stackexchange sites for these topics if they do exist.

Just on a side-note: is a smartphone a mobile device? As in iPhones?

Comment: Depends on what you're doing with that smartphone doesn't it?

Comment: True, trouble connecting your smartphone to your computer is kinda grey area...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/are-iphone-ipod-and-ipod-touch-questions-computer-related-super-user

Comment: "cellphones or mobile devices excluding iPhones" should really be "excluding smartphones", I guess, because then for example, why iPhone questions would be ok when Android-based would not? It's just a matter of coherence. Or simply no exceptions for iPhones, only computer questions.

Comment: Actually, the updated FAQ is more general, about smartphones, I notice. Good, so.

Comment: Actually I would like Android questions more than iPhone ones :P

Answer (score 2):

Great idea Diago!  I can link to the FAQ more often instead of meta discussions. I don't think it will calm people down any when their questions get closed, but at least it will be officially stated in the FAQ from now on. Thanks to Jeff for updating this.

Oh, and congrats to Ivo on joining the SU mod team!

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you very much!

Comment: Congrats to you too, Troggy, obviously :P