# Why are smartphone-related questions considered off-topic on superuser.com?

Tags: discussion, questions, allowed-topics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is a modern phone not a computer?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2877/is-a-modern-phone-not-a-computer)

In the F.A.Q. it is written that the site is about questions about "computer software" and "not about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer"

In my opinion a smartphone is mainly a mini-computer (with a telephone function) that interacts with my other computer(s) (and many other computers on the internet). So this phrasing is... not good.

The distinction becomes more ridiculous when people write [stuff like this](https://meta.superuser.com/a/420/153404):

> No, Superuser won't allow them unless the problem also involves a "real" computer.

I can understand the problems with the types of questions that would arise; but then the phrasing and reasoning should be different in the rules.

I have read this discussion [Update the Super User FAQ](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/757/update-the-super-user-faq) and there is not much too see about my specific question.

and on another discussion, [this answer](https://meta.superuser.com/a/418/153404) got 10 upvotes

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3306/how-is-the-term-computer-defined-on-super-user may be of interest here. I'd also note there're places for at least the big two phone OSes - ask different does IOS, and android.se does android.

Comment: oh thanks for the second link; that is even more meta! :)